# HttpServletRequest & HttpServletResponse declared as final

Tags: java, servlets, final

What happens if I declare HttpServletRequest as final & HttpServletResponse as final in a **doPost** method. 
I am trying to test that in a login page.

Comment: do you have an understanding of the `final` keyword? That means you will not be able to reassign the object after initialization.  That's what happens when you add final to those types.

Comment: so there will be no difference in using request1 & request2, if I declare `final HttpServletRequest request1` or `HttpServletRequest request2`

Comment: @Anjigadu that's what I'm saying in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It won't affect your application, you just can not modify their references in the `doPost` method, but even if you could (by not marking them as `final`) you should not even attempt to do it. It would be a **very bad idea** to modify these references. Still, even by declaring them as `final` you can modify their state e.g. adding and removing attributes in request.

There's a good explanation about `final` parameters here: [final keyword in method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236599/1065197)