# What's the difference between final parameters and non-final ones in Java?

Tags: java, parameters, final

I have read some source codes. In the package of util, I saw much usage of 'final' keyword. For instance, there is a method in PrefUtil.java:

```
public static void setAttendeeAtVenue(final Context context, final boolean isAtVenue) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_ATTENDEE_AT_VENUE, isAtVenue).commit();
}
```

In this method, all parameters are modified by 'final'. And I encountered a few cases like this somewhere else. But I didn't understand the effect of 'final'. So, I ask for help here to erase questions in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Using `final` ensures that the *references* being passed are not reassigned. You can modify the object to which the reference points. Thus, your object is not *immutable*, it is still mutable but the reference cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

`final` means you can't change the value of that variable once it was assigned

The use of `final` for the arguments in those methods means it won't allow the programmer to change their value during the execution of the method.

Answer (score 0):

`final` on parameter will prevent code inside method to rewrite it.

Rewriting parameter values is bad practice since it's very difficult to maintain such code.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I got it. And there is the similar question with me, whose url is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236599/final-keyword-in-method-parameters

Comment: Yeah, but parameters are not rewritted. So 'final' is unnecessary, right?

Comment: @LittlePanpc, well, methods can grow quickly, so `final` here is to protect params from future changes. But, on my projects `final` on params is used very rarely.