# immutable final arguments and returns

Tags: java

Can non-final arguments or returned objects make an object mutable?

What difference does it make by changing this:

```
public final class MyImmutableClass {

public final MyObject doStuff(final SomeObject someObject) {
    ...
}

}
```

to this:

```
public final class MyImmutableClass {

public MyObject doStuff(SomeObject someObject) {
    ...
}

}
```

When the goal is to make `MyImmutableClass` truly immutable.

After appling the change, is `MyImmutableClass` still considered immutable? If not, what state could be altered by making the changes?

Comment: IIRC making a class final doesn't affect mutability. It just means that the class can't be subclassed

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236599/final-keyword-in-method-parameters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all a *class* is never *immutable*, an instance of a class could be. Next,

`public final MyObject doStuff(final SomeObject someObject) {`

Here, you can't change the reference `someObject` to point to some other instance of `SomeObject` inside the method. This guarantees that you are always using the argument passed by the caller.

Next, `final` in a method signature ensures that it cannot be overridden (which is redundant if the class itself is marked as `final`.)