# why should we use final to mark the constructor parameter in enum?

Tags: java, enums

I've seen the question in [Best way to create enum of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978654/best-way-to-create-enum-of-strings/3978690#3978690)
, and I found that they used final in the constructor parameter, I think it's unnecessary, anyone can tell me why? thanks..

Comment: Same answer as for why you do it on a method.

Comment: Do you know what `final` means? Maybe this can help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500508/why-should-i-use-the-keyword-final-on-a-method-parameter-in-java` or this one `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236599/final-keyword-in-method-parameters` . In general, it is not necessary.