# Final method arguments vs re-declaration of arguments as final variables in the method

Tags: java, final

I found a method similar to the following:

```
private void methodA(String firstArg, String secondArg) {
    final String queueFirstArg = firstArg;
    final String queueSecondArg = secondArg;
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           methodB(queueFirstArg, queueSecondArg);
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like bad code and making both arguments 'final' would be enough. 
Am I missing something? Is there any benefit in using that approach?

Comment: What problems come from bad coding style? I don't know what kind of answer you want to get here. The code you posted it not good, like the other people already said. So i think the question is answered now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's "bad code" because of redundant local variables, because you can add *final* to arguments without afraid to change caller behavior, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236599/final-keyword-in-method-parameters):

> Java always makes a copy of parameters before sending them to methods. This means the final doesn't mean any difference for the calling code.